# JSON big query = pass the schema

Tags: google-bigquery

Create table in GBQ with JSONed dataset.

could you give an example on this ?

Thanks in advance !

regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 1):

found the answer

command -

./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON test_schema:test_dataset.test_table_name gs://test_gs_location/* ./test.json